# Mobile Services Authentication with Facebook always gives Unauthorized error

Tags: facebook, azure, unity-game-engine, azure-mobile-services

I've been trying to create unity application and connect it with mobile services. I'm trying to do FB authentication and here's what I've done on my checklist :

1. Registered my FB App Id and App secret properly on mobile services.
2. For testing I use FB tools to generate access token for now.

Here's my code to login to FB using Restsharp :

```
// token is hardcoded with access token from FB tools for test
AuthenticationToken authToken = CreateToken(provider, token);
_LoginAsyncCallback = callback;

var path = "/login/" + provider.ToString().ToLower();
var baseClient = new RestClient(_baseEndPoint);
var request = new RestRequest(path, Method.POST);
var json = SerializeObject(authToken);

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

var handle = baseClient.ExecuteAsync<MobileServiceUser>(request, LoginAsyncHandler);
```

provider is `facebook` and my post is `"access_token":"XXXXXXXX"` so this should be correct right?

I always get this error :

> Rest Response:{"code":401,"error":"Error: The Facebook Graph API access token authorization request failed with HTTP status code 400"}

I've tried many FB app settings and generate new access tokens from FB tools, etc but nothing seems to work. I'm at my wits end on this

Comment: did you provided the tokens and the keys in the azure portal https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication/#secrets

Comment: yes,
both on the FB app settings I put my endpoints url as the app domain and on the mobile services identity settings I put the FB App id and app secret

I've been trying with various advanced settings of FB app but nothing works. I looked around many tutorials but they don't mention much about FB app settings

Comment: can you show me the path that this request is hitting and the dump of the data, (fudge the data if you have any concerns)

Comment: it should be https://juarabulu.azure-mobile.net/login/facebook 
I tried to foloow this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj710106.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

and it seems that I did but I don't know what went wrong there. I tried to trace using fiddler and charles but my calls didn't show up to trace the package.. any idea?